# How could we replace the primary image of the default entity 'User' in Dynamics CRM?

Tags: dynamics-crm

I need help in changing the primary image and replacing it with a new icon for certain default entities in Dynamics CRM .

Answer (score 0):

This is only doable for custom entities as far as I'm aware. You do have two potential options

1) If you're running On Premise then you can go into the folder structure on the CRM server. Find where CRM is installed (I can't recall the directory) and dig around in the CRMWeb folder looking for the entity icons. If you replace the images and do an iisreset that could work.

2) Failing that, add the entity you want to change the icon for to an unmanaged solution and export it. Extract the solution file and open customizations.xml in a text editor. Look under the Entity element for anything relating to the icon. You should see a relative path url to the file on the server. If you have a web resource you want to use as an icon you can replace the url with "$webresource:[uniquenameoficon]" without the quotes. E.g. "$webresource:new_icon.png"

Comment: Thanks Mark ! Let me try the second solution and analyze the outcome.